# Parsing XHTML in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, parsing, xhtml

I need to parse the XHTML file at http://www.ridgefield.org/ajax/dist/emergency-announcements for emergency announcements in an iPhone app.  Its from my school website, so I can assume pretty valid code.  Can I use NSXMLParser?  Any other suggestions would be accepted, I am new to web parsing.

Comment: Assuming valid markup is not a good idea. Taking a look at it right now, it isn't a valid document (no root node, just a `div` and a comment node)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would stick with the NSXMLParser, as it will be supported by apple in the future. It's pretty easy too!

Follow the guide provided by apple here :
[Apple Developer Event driven XML parsing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html)

Comment: Could i feed it an XHTML document though?

Comment: Yes. If I where in your shoes though I'd get with the sys admin at the school and tell them you'd like to make an app for the system. Maybe he could output it in xml just for you. You'd be surprised how helpful they can be.